# hacer la peticion POST desde el controlador

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo la necesidad de hacer una peticion POST desde el controlador antes de cargar la vista, deseo hacer esto debido a cierta condición que me es exigida.

La condición es:

> Si tengo mas de un producto en contrato mostrar un "Menú" con los productos contratados, de lo contrario si solo tengo 1 mostrar la vista de ese producto y no el "Menú".

El código del controlador del Menú es:

```
public ActionResult MenuApps(){
  if (WSKernel.Suscriptions_WebDevices_Get(productosDatos, out productosRespuesta)) {
    model.Productos = productosRespuesta.ListSuscriptions_WebDevices;
    //si solo se cuenta con un solo producto, hacer redireccion directa al unico producto
    if (model.Productos != null && model.Productos.Length == 1){
      switch (model.Productos[0].AdmixProduct){
        case "Producto1":
          return Redirect("http://localhost/Producto1");
        case "Producto2":
          return Redirect("http://localhost/Producto2");
      }
    }
  }else{//sin productos}
}
```

Pero el hacer `return Redirect("http://localhost/Producto2");` hace una peticion `HTTP` por `GET` ya que deseo hacer envió de informacion y deseo que el usuario no la visualice solo por el hecho de que necesito que siempre inicie sesión correctamente.

Por otro lado a donde quiero redirigir es otro proyecto que ya esta terminado y este esta configurado para recibir informacion por POST.

**¿Como puedo hacer la peticion POST y redirigir a la pagina desde el controlador?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Primeramente mi idea era retornar un script con una peticion AJAX desde Javascript, pero me encontraba con el problema de que no podía redirigir a la pagina, entonces no era lo que necesitaba.
2. Me propuse retornar una vista con un formulario, pero el problema era que siempre me aparecía la pagina en blanco y hacia la petición, tampoco era muy bien visto.

Después de varios intentos y mucha búsqueda encontré con este [post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET) donde explica los intentos que hizo, pero al parecer mi segunda idea iba por buen camino, solo que en la pagina lo hace con un `Helper`.

**La idea del `Helper` es simple:**
*para cada valor de la clave que desea publicar, creamos un campo oculto, creamos el formulario, a continuación, añadimos la secuencia de comandos necesarios para hacer el envío automático llamando `vPostForm.submit()` desde el código JavaScript*.

Por lo tanto el código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
private static String PreparePOSTForm(string url, NameValueCollection data)
{
    //Set a name for the form
    string formID = "PostForm";
    //Build the form using the specified data to be posted.
    StringBuilder strForm = new StringBuilder();
    strForm.Append("<form id=\"" + formID + "\" name=\"" + 
                   formID + "\" action=\"" + url + 
                   "\" method=\"POST\">");

    foreach (string key in data)
    {
        strForm.Append("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"" + key + 
                       "\" value=\"" + data[key] + "\">");
    }

    strForm.Append("</form>");
    //Build the JavaScript which will do the Posting operation.
    StringBuilder strScript = new StringBuilder();
    strScript.Append("<script language="'javascript'">");
    strScript.Append("var v" + formID + " = document." + 
                     formID + ";");
    strScript.Append("v" + formID + ".submit();");
    strScript.Append("</script>");
    //Return the form and the script concatenated.
    //(The order is important, Form then JavaScript)
    return strForm.ToString() + strScript.ToString();
}
```

Ahora para consumir este método privado se necesita lo siguiente:

```
public static void RedirectAndPOST(Page page, string destinationUrl, NameValueCollection data)
{
  //Prepare the Posting form
  string strForm = PreparePOSTForm(destinationUrl, data);
  //Add a literal control the specified page holding 
  //the Post Form, this is to submit the Posting form with the request.
  page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(strForm));
}
```

bien, ahora en mi controlador usaría algo como esto:

```
Dictionary<string, object> postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postData.Add("first", "someValueOne");
postData.Add("second", "someValueTwo");
return this.RedirectAndPost("http://TheUrlToPostDataTo", postData);
```

Ahora si, se cumple la condición que tenia que respetar:

> *Si tengo mas de un producto en contrato mostrar un "Menú" con los productos contratados, de lo contrario si solo tengo 1 mostrar la
>   vista de ese producto y no el "Menú".*

[Código y crédito de **Samer Abu Rabie**](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=3456243)

---

Si bien deseas hacer algo más simple en MVC existe el [paquete Nuget como Fluentx.Mvc (Recomendado)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fluentx.Mvc/), en el cual ya no necesitas crear el helper en un archivo, solo es necesario la importación del paquete con `using Fluentx.Mvc;`

Para usarlo es de la misma manera.

```
Dictionary<string, object> postData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postData.Add("first", "someValueOne");
postData.Add("second", "someValueTwo");
return this.RedirectAndPost("http://TheUrlToPostDataTo", postData);
```